# RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0 even if the provider is called before

Tags: flutter, frontend

When I try to call the first Album in my Item list, they say me that this list is empty.

But I'm sure that I call my API with `fetchAndSetAlbum()` in `initState` function before.

It seems that the list is empty in the first compute, but it's ok after this because the album is showed even the error is printed. But I don't want to work with error.

```
class CellCurrentProject extends StatefulWidget {
  final Album? selectedAlbum;

  CellCurrentProject({
    Key? key,
    this.selectedAlbum,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CellCurrentProject> createState() => _CellCurrentProjectState();
}

class _CellCurrentProjectState extends State<CellCurrentProject> {

  //var _isInit = true;
```

```
class CellCurrentProject extends StatefulWidget {
  final Album? selectedAlbum;

  CellCurrentProject({
    Key? key,
    this.selectedAlbum,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CellCurrentProject> createState() => _CellCurrentProjectState();
}

class _CellCurrentProjectState extends State<CellCurrentProject> {

  //var _isInit = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<Albums>(context, listen: false).fetchAndSetAlbums();
  }


  Album? selectedAlbum;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    selectedAlbum = Provider.of<SelectedAlbum>(context).album;

    if (selectedAlbum == null) {
      selectedAlbum = Provider.of<Albums>(context).items[0]; // here the error
    }

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: gris,
...
```

Wid

I tried with didchangedependencies but the same problem.
I try with initState in the parent widget but it doesn't work

Comment: I assume that `fetchAndSetAlbums` is an async function, and `initState` can't wait for it. Check out [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

your `fetchAndSetAlbums` is most likely async and takes time to finish. You probably will want to use a `FutureBuilder` or alternatively something like this:

```
class _CellCurrentProjectState extends State<CellCurrentProject> {

  var _isInit = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadAlbums();
  }

  Future loadAlbums() async {
    await Provider.of<Albums>(context, listen: false).fetchAndSetAlbums();
    setState(() {
      _isInit = true;
    });
  }


  Album? selectedAlbum;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_isInit) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    selectedAlbum = Provider.of<SelectedAlbum>(context).album;

    if (selectedAlbum == null) {
      selectedAlbum = Provider.of<Albums>(context).items[0]; // here the error
    }

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: gris,
```